# Error installing models for python

Tags: python

- Python Version : 3.4.0
- Pip Version : 9.0.1
- Windows 10

I'm trying to install models from pip and getting the following error.

```
pip install models

Collecting models

  Using cached models-0.9.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\KANIKA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p46tenn_\models\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        import models
      File "C:\Users\KANIKA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p46tenn_\models\models\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from base import *
    ImportError: No module named 'base'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KANIKA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p46tenn_\models\
```

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: The last release of `models` in pypi was Feb 20, 2010, so I would guess there are incompatibilities?

Comment: Also there might be specific problems in your path, check the output of `sys.path`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/models/0.9.7) -

"Since 21 Feb 2010 this package is named “PyModels”. It was renamed due to name clashes between the library and local module with concrete models. It is natural to name the latter “models.py” (e.g. in Django), so it would obviously conflict with an external library named “models”."

So may be you can try with - **pip install pymodels**, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to install for Django only

Comment: Using pip install pymodels also gives the same error

Comment: Then there could be a path and installation issue. According to @Ofer Sadan's comment, check your sys.path output, what all paths is it showing.